# Ruby on Rails Heroku App exited with status 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I was running Heroku ruby on rails app.

After I run `heroku run rails db:migrate` it run the command but on the page it still looks like this:

[image]

I tried to run the command `heroku logs -t` and I got the ff:

```
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669437+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669439+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669441+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669443+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669445+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669447+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669449+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669451+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2020-01-07T10:50:44.669454+00:00 app[web.1]: [eba0b178-2344-4fa0-8054-275ff569d476] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-01-07T10:50:45.107482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=8b444e49-ff2e-46db-bb7b-b367b86b327e fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:50:46.747672+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88 fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:50:46.739000+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-01-07T10:50:46.738881 #4]  INFO -- : [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] Started GET "/" for 120.29.104.35 at 2020-01-07 10:50:46 +0000
2020-01-07T10:50:46.739625+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:50:46.739563 #4] FATAL -- : [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88]
2020-01-07T10:50:46.744978+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:50:46.744902 #4] FATAL -- : [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745078+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:50:46.745010 #4] FATAL -- : [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88]
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745226+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:50:46.745138 #4] FATAL -- : [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745229+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745232+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745235+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745237+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745239+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745241+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745243+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745245+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745247+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745249+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745251+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745253+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745255+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745257+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745259+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745261+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745263+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745266+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745268+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745270+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2020-01-07T10:50:46.745272+00:00 app[web.1]: [a42eccb6-24f0-490c-a5f7-7e64eade6f88] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-01-07T10:50:47.231779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=c943531d-1880-40a4-bf05-76be64cbffe4 fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:51:18.152350+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate` by user samuelnico.norton@gmail.com
2020-01-07T10:51:23.083576+00:00 heroku[run.2849]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-07T10:51:23.026997+00:00 heroku[run.2849]: Awaiting client
2020-01-07T10:51:23.056804+00:00 heroku[run.2849]: Starting process with command `rails db:migrate`
2020-01-07T10:51:32.183783+00:00 heroku[run.2849]: State changed from up to complete
2020-01-07T10:51:32.171183+00:00 heroku[run.2849]: Process exited with status 0
2020-01-07T10:51:49.687345+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-01-07T10:51:49.687233 #4]  INFO -- : [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] Started GET "/" for 120.29.104.35 at 2020-01-07 10:51:49 +0000
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688060+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:51:49.687986 #4] FATAL -- : [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad]
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688148+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:51:49.688094 #4] FATAL -- : [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688223+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:51:49.688173 #4] FATAL -- : [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad]
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688338+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:51:49.688274 #4] FATAL -- : [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688341+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688344+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688347+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688349+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688351+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688353+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688355+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688357+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688359+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688361+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688363+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688366+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688368+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688370+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688372+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688374+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688376+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688378+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688381+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688383+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.688385+00:00 app[web.1]: [fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-01-07T10:51:49.689497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=fe9ed228-1d90-48ce-a5bf-51d25cbaaaad fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:51:50.392917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=914a32bb-c47f-4252-8873-0c271b66fed7 fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:52:48.828733+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0 fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2020-01-07T10:52:48.826358+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-01-07T10:52:48.826212 #4]  INFO -- : [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] Started GET "/" for 120.29.104.35 at 2020-01-07 10:52:48 +0000
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827493+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:52:48.827014 #4] FATAL -- : [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0]
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827588+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:52:48.827503 #4] FATAL -- : [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827680+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:52:48.827590 #4] FATAL -- : [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0]
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827799+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-01-07T10:52:48.827701 #4] FATAL -- : [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827802+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827804+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827807+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827809+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827811+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827814+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827816+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827818+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827820+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827823+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827827+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827829+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827832+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827834+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827836+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.4.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827838+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827840+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:674:in `handle_request'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827842+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827844+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
2020-01-07T10:52:48.827846+00:00 app[web.1]: [2f4a0782-4b68-4b48-a372-5e12861575d0] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/puma-3.12.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2020-01-07T10:52:49.268499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=serene-escarpment-40321.herokuapp.com request_id=92762c68-79fd-4790-95b1-4c60941ee081 fwd="120.29.104.35" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143 protocol=https
```

Installed the Heroku on my local workstation. This ensures that I have access to the Heroku command-line client, Foreman, and the Git revision control system.

Not sure what's going on it says something about exited with 0. Please help!

Comment: Hey! Add your routes please

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have the root route inside of it, to fix it just add `root to: 'controller#action'`

Answer (score 0):

First, create a test controller:

```
rails g controller welcome index
```

Next, populate the `views/welcome/index.html.erb` file with any text:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
```

Go to `routes.rb`:

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

Dont forget to push to git and heroku.

Problem is solved.